# opencsv writing file with some quoted elements and others unquoted

Tags: java, opencsv

Does anyone have experience using opencsv in Java to write a csv file where only some of the elements need to be double quoted? The desired output I am looking to test is to make a file that would read:

`1,"two",three`

but when I try the following code

```
writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
String[] entries = {"1","\"two\"","three"};
writer.writeNext(entries);
writer.close();
```

the following output occurs

`1,""two"",three`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

These extra quotes are the escape characters used by `OpenCSV`. You need to use the [overloaded constructor](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#CSVWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20char,%20char,%20char%29) that allows you to turn off these:

```
writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',', 
           CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);
...
```

Output:

```
1,"two",three
```

Comment: the "no escape character" paramter will badly mess up with characters that need escaping in your String fields